# data attr binding is not working with [innerHTML] Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, attributes, translate

I'm using a variable which has  tag along with data attribute (data-title) once angular is rendered, data attr is not visible in view. Other default attr like class, id are working as-usual.

I've tried both *attr.data-title="some text"*  and *[attr.data-title]="{some text}"*.

This is how my code looks:

```
let VARIABLE_TO_CHANGE = "Hello <span [attr.data-title]='test'>{name}</span>"

<div [innerHTML]="('VARIBLE_TO_CHANGE'|translate).replace('{name}', 'world')"></div>
```

If I see the result in browser inspect element, I expect to see

```
Hello <span data-title="test">world</span>
```

But what I see,

```
Hello <span>world</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one: `let VARIABLE_TO_CHANGE = "Hello <span data-title='test'>{name}</span>"`

Comment: Tried @VitaliiIlchenko , not working.

Comment: Is it something to do with [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml)?

Answer (score 1):

use a `safeHtm`l pipe with `.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #div [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></div>1`,
})
```

Sure it will work

Comment: Thank you @Ajas Aju. Good idea :)